# не могу в data = b" " засунуть переменную

Tags: python, telethon

```
checker = str(event.message.to_dict()['reply_markup'])
i = checker.rindex("'") - 1
a = ""

while checker[i] != "'":
    a = a + checker[i]
    i -= 1      
       
sleep(1)
await event.message.click(data=b'%s' % a)
```

я пытаюсь написать скрипт, который будет смотреть содержание data у inline кнопки, и потом это содержание добавлять в переменную и подставлять в message.click. Но проблема в том, что он почему то не работает, не высвечивает даже ошибку, когда я добавляю конструкцию в try/except, у меня except перехватывает ошибку, но я не знаю ее тип, так что я в замешательстве, заранее спасибо

Comment: Так что за исключение? Печатать пробовали его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для того, чтобы "засунуть" строку в тип bytes воспользуйтесь готовым методом `bytes`:

```
a = b"abrakadabra"
type(a)
# bytes
b = bytes("abrakadabra", encoding="utf8")
type(b)
# bytes
a == b
# True
type(a) == type(b)
# True
```

хотя вопрос "зачем?" остается открытым.